# By how much could we accelerate medical development of a vaccine for a pandemic?

Tags: virus

Imagine a worst case scenario. Millions of people infected by an virus in the west. Governments willing to provide all ressources, no matter the cost. Could a hugely increased budget even be effectively used to accelerate the development of a drug or is the bottelneck somewhere else?

I'm considering an effort on the scale of the Manhattan project.

**To clarify I'm looking for scientific studies or even better papers issued by a major government discussing this.**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103870/discussion-on-question-by-theoreticalminimum-by-how-much-could-we-accelerate-med).

Comment: Usually a death threat is a strong motivation catalyzer, would it be coming from a war or from a disease. That should have an impact on resources, and deeply motivate researchers, as it triggers the survival instinct. Then, by how much is a difficult question.

Comment: Here is a paper, 2018, Nature Reviews Microbiology, “Origin and Evolution  of Pathogenic Coronaviruses” Joe Cui et al. https://www.nature.com/articles/s41579-018-0118-9#ref-CR71 I am putting the link here though it may not be 100% relevant to your question nevertheless it may provide some background.

Comment: How quickly did an Ebola vaccine become available once there was a significantly serious threat? I think that says a lot.